# Click listener event doesn't fire on SVG element (font awesome icon)

Tags: jquery, svg, font-awesome, event-listener, jquery-events

There are icons on a page with class `close` (the icon is an x which closes a div). In the browser, the font awesome loads in HTML as an `<svg>` element with a `<path>` element as a child. Using slim, the code is as follows:

`= icon :times, class: 'close'`

An event listener is being added to the icons in the JS as follows:

```
(function($) {

  function closeDialog() { ... }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close').on('click', closeDialog);
  }

})(jQuery);
```

After the page loads, the event does not fire when you click on the X icon. However, if I add the `close` class to any other element other than the font-awesome icon, it will trigger correctly when clicked. Also, if I copy and paste the JS into the console and run it, then clicking the SVG element triggers the event.

Currently, my solution is to wrap the SVG in a div and give the div the `close` class. It works, but I would like to understand why the original did not.

Working solution:

```
.close
  = icon :times
```

Comment: try to delegate the event: $(document).on('click', '.close', closeDialog);

Comment: This could be due to a few different things. Please create a [mcve] so we can see the issue in a real example.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking here, this has info about how click events are handled for SVG elements. If it is set to none or some other odd option, it won't detect clicks on the SVG

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

This issue is similar to when you have an SVG icon on a button or span or something, then you click the icon but the event of the parent doesn't get fired

Set `pointer-events` to `none` to allow the click passing through, if your icon is an SVG, something like this will help:

```
.element svg{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```